# python bluetooth discover does not show all devices

Tags: python, bluetooth

I have a problem with my bluetooth smart scale.
I can discover it on my android mobile.
But when I run this code (in python2 and python3):

```
import bluetooth
bluetooth.discover_devices()
```

Then it returns empty list []

Also when I run these commands:

```
bluetoothctl
[bluetooth]# power on
[bluetooth]# agent on
[bluetooth]# default-agent
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller 00:15:83:4F:32:56 Discovering: yes
[CHG] Device F0:C7:7F:2A:8D:CA RSSI: -83
[CHG] Device F0:C7:7F:2A:8D:CA ManufacturerData Key: 0x0000
[CHG] Device F0:C7:7F:2A:8D:CA ManufacturerData Value: 0xf0
[CHG] Device F0:C7:7F:2A:8D:CA ManufacturerData Value: 0xc7
[CHG] Device F0:C7:7F:2A:8D:CA ManufacturerData Value: 0x7f
[CHG] Device F0:C7:7F:2A:8D:CA ManufacturerData Value: 0x2a
[CHG] Device F0:C7:7F:2A:8D:CA ManufacturerData Value: 0x8d
[CHG] Device F0:C7:7F:2A:8D:CA ManufacturerData Value: 0xca
```

The scale is discovered.
Does anybody have idea, why the pybluez is not able to discover this device?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you running your Python code as root?

Comment: I just tried it. It is the same. Anyway my bluetooth headset is detected by python.

Comment: Could it be a Bluetooth LE device? Then try this https://github.com/karulis/pybluez/blob/master/examples/ble/scan.py

Comment: Hey it works! Thanks. I must start study what is LE device :)